# Withoutoverlapping not working as expected for queued Laravel Job

Tags: laravel

I have this Laravel queued job that runs whenever an Order is fully paid on the platform that we're building. It simply sets the order-number (sequential number).

```
class SetOrderNumberJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    private Firm $firm;
    private Order $order;
    private Connection $redis;

    public function __construct(Firm $firm, Order $order)
    {
        $this->onQueue('order-number');

        $this->firm = $firm;
        $this->order = $order;

        $this->redis = Redis::connection();
    }

    public function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            new WithoutOverlapping($this->firm->id)
        ];
    }

    public function retryUntil()
    {
        return now()->addSeconds(30);
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $currentDay = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
        $redisKey = 'firm-order-number.' . $currentDay . '.' . $this->order->firm->id;

        $nextOrderNumber = $this->getNextNumber($this->order, $redisKey);

        $this->order->number = $nextOrderNumber;
        $this->order->save();

        $this->redis->set($redisKey, $nextOrderNumber);
    }

    private function getNextNumber(Order $order, string $redisKey): string
    {
        $lastOrderNumber = $this->redis->get($redisKey);

        return $lastOrderNumber + 1;
    }
```

This is the Horizon supervisor config that I've setup:

```
'supervisor-fast' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['order-number'],
    'processes' => 3,
    'balance' => 'auto',
    'autoScalingStrategy' => 'time',
    'timeout' => 5, // in seconds
],
```

Whenever I dispatch a lot of orders (e.g. more than 50) for the same firmId, all at once, to stresstest this functionality: then I see some order-records having the same order-number.

I would expect that not to happen because of the WithoutOverlapping Job middleware that I applied to this job. Which would mean that this job should never have concurrent processes handling jobs for the same firmId.

As you can see in the Horizon supervisor config, I've set the processes to be 3.
Please note that if I set the processes to 1, then all my orders have unique, sequential numbers.

What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated :D

Comment: Just to be sure: In this context `$this->firm->id` is the same as `$this->order->firm->id`?

Comment: Yes, that’s right :)

Comment: Will it make any difference if you remove `$this->redis = Redis::connection();` from the constructor and instead do `$lastOrderNumber = Redis::connection()->get($redisKey)` ?